# How to insert into a value an HTML insert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to do a simple login form that just compare the value that you insert into the input in HTML to the data you had in the database. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a controller and compare the params hash.

```
expected_value = '...'
if params[:form_value] == expected_value
  do_something()
else
  do_something_else()
end
```